# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:7245/api/ftpconfiguration/retrieveftpdetails'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to call a function named 'RetrieveFtpDetails'  in  'FtpConfiguration' controller in web-service 'APIService'.Also this web service is created as a new project from an existing project.

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "API" }
            );
}
```

and FtpConfiguration controller looks like:

```
public class FtpConfigurationController : ApiController
{
 [Route("api/ftpconfiguration/retrieveftpdetails")]
 [HttpPost]
 public List<string> RetrieveFtpDetails() 
 {
  List<string> lstftpcongif;
  using (APM context = new APM())
  {
   lstftpcongif = (from s in context.M_FtpConfigTable select 
                   s.Mode).ToList();
  }
  return lstftpcongif;
 }
}
```

and then I called http://localhost:7245/api/ftpconfiguration/retrieveftpdetails/ then get a result like below:

```
    <Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:7245/api/ftpconfiguration/retrieveftpdetails'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'ftpconfiguration'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Why i am getting this error ?

Comment: Why do you have `[HttpPost]` on the method?  How are you hitting the URL to test it?

Answer (score 0):

I thing your localhost url is not correct.

1)check your web api url or fix the port of localhost for webapi .so there is no error.
2)see the example 
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/W69E040815-CRUD-Operations-with-AngularJS,-RequireJS-and-WebAPI.html

by using this you can solve your error .

May be this helps you .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues:

1. You are using `[HttpPost]` - make sure you are using POST to test this action.
2. You route defaults to `API` controller - make sure you have one.
3. You have invalid route template - since it contains `action`, you are clearly missing it with your route. I suggest changing it to following:

   ```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Route",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "FtpConfiguration" }
       );

       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "API" }
       );
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Try This : WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "API" }
            );
}
```